# custom rule for validate input does not contain bad words

Tags: laravel, api, validation, rules

i have an API with different tables like : posts , questions , comments and .. and i don't want to allow users to use bad words to fill in the fields of these tables and show them error while using these words.

so i searched and wrote this FormRequest for validate category description :

```
 public function rules(){
        Validator::extend('not_contains', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
            // Banned words
            $words = array('f***', 's***' , 'a****' , 'b***');
                foreach ($words as $word) {
                    if (stripos($value, $word) !== false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            return true;
        });


        $rules = [
            'description'=>['required','max:500' ,'not_contains'],
        ];

        if ('PUT' === $this->method()) {
            $rules['title'] = 'required|unique:categories,id,' . $this->route('category_id');
        }
        else{
            $rules['title'] = 'required|unique:categories|';
        }

            return $rules;
    }

}
```

it worked but i I don't want to use this `not_contains` code in any formRequest , so i created this custom Rule :

```
class CheckBadWords implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        Validator::extend('bad_words', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
            // Banned words
            $words = array('f***', 's***' , 'a****' , 'b***');
            foreach ($words as $word) {
                if (stripos($value, $word) !== false) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'bad word used!';
    }
}
```

and in form request i added this to $rules :

```
   $rules = [
            'description'=>['required','max:500' ,new checkBadWords()],
        ];
```

so when i send request , this rule works for every contain and give validation error : `bad word used!` even for content that does not contain these bad words

Comment: are using php 8 ?

Comment: no i use php 7.4.3

Comment: i have updated answer

Comment: There are a few packages that cater for this uses case, [this one looks reasonable](https://github.com/developerdino/ProfanityFilter) albeit not updated for a while. Most of what you require is already done but you could for the repo if you really needed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your rule classes passes() method to

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $words = array('f***', 's***' , 'a****' , 'b***');

    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (stripos($value, $word) !== false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: i tried it and works but there is a difference  , When I use your code, users can get around  rule by pasting words into other words like : fu%ckf*ck , 
But my code recognized this

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom rule like below

```
class CheckBadWords implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string $attribute
     * @param  mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $words = array('f***', 's***' , 'a****' , 'b***');
        $wordFound = false;
        foreach ($words as $badword) {

            if (str_contains($value, $badword)) {
                $wordFound = true;
                break;
            }


        }

        if ($wordFound) {

            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }


/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return 'bad word used!';
}
}
```

if you are not using latest version of php then change `str_contains` to `stripos`